What happens if a current or former US president attempts to stand for a third term
The 22nd Amendment to the US Constitution states that:

No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice

There are currently four living former Presidents who have been elected twice and could therefore attempt to breach this limit (Bill Clinton, George W. Bush, Barack Obama and Donald Trump). What would happen if they attempted to do this, in terms of stopping them and punishing them?
Would they be stopped:

When they stand for election as their party's nominee in an open primary.
When they are chosen as their party's nominee.
When they apply to appear on the ballot paper.
When they are elected.

The amendment seems to only bar election, rather than standing for election, and a candidate could fail at any point before the last one (e.g. if they lose the electoral college vote).
Also, if someone does attempt a third term and ends up being prevented, is there any punishment for attempting to break a constitutional term-limit?
I don't think anyone has ever attempted this for the Presidential election, so there may be no direct precedent, but are there examples of other term-limited offices where someone has attempted to ignore the limits (successfully or not) which would give an indication of what might happen?
Just to be clear, I'm not asking how someone could get around the term-limit (there are plenty of questions discussing this), but what would happen in terms of process and punishment if they attempted to stand for election for a third time.

The "what happens/what would happen/would they be stopped" part of the question is too close to predicting the future. Is it allowed or not within the current framework? What would need to happen to make it legal? History has quite some examples.

I don't think it is predicting the future. If you want to look at it another way, you could see it as asking 'what does the current legal framework (including precedent from previous similar cases, if any) say about trying to breach the term limit (including process and punishment)'. I am explicitly not asking what would need to happen to make it legal.

But you are also asking if they would be stopped or what would happen if they tried to attempt it. How can anyone know that now? Nobody does.

We'll find out when and if it happens.

As far as I can tell, it is not a crime to run for any elected office in the US as an unqualified candidate. That said, there are a huge number of roadblocks that prevent unqualified candidates from being elected and then taking office.
Roadblock #1: Getting on the ballot.
It is up to election officials (typically headed by a state's Secretary of State) to keep unqualified candidates off the ballot. If a candidate is not qualified (and that includes running as a third term president), said candidate should not be appearing on the ballot. Some states even require potential write-in candidates to be qualified.
Roadblock #2: Ballot counters.
Assuming the election officials did their job, the official ballot counters don't need to worry about excluding votes for unqualified candidates. In states that don't certify who is/is not qualified to run for an office as a write-in candidate, they might have to toss write-in votes for, example, Mickey Mouse (a favorite write-in, where allowed).
Roadblock #3: The Electoral College.
The Electors swear an oath to the US Constitution, which includes the 22nd Amendment. In some states it has even been made a crime to be a Faithless Elector. That sets up a quandary if the winning candidate in some state passes the first two roadblocks but is indeed unqualified. Said electors are caught between a rock and a hard place. They might be violating state law by being faithless and voting against the elected unqualified candidate, but they might be violating state law by violating the US Constitution.
Roadblock #4: The US Congress.
The US Congress meets in a joint session on January 6 to certify the presidential election results. One of the things they are supposed to do is to certify that the winning candidates from each state are qualified to be president.Constitution.
Roadblock #5: The US Supreme Court.
Suppose that somehow an unqualified presidential candidate did make it past all of the previously mentioned roadblocks and has been elected. Everyone who opposes this election will qualify as an aggrieved party; their appeals will quickly make their way to the Supreme Court. The Court's number one job is to ensure the Constitution is obeyed.
Anti-roadblock #1: Side-skirt the 22nd Amendment.
There is one path to being a third term president that does not require being elected three times. This would be a reenactment of Woodrow Wilson's bizarre scheme in 1916 should Wilson have not been elected to a second term. (He was narrowly reelected in the Electoral College so Wilson's bizarre scheme was never put into play.) The issue at hand back then was the very long lame duck session between the November election and the March 4 presidential transition. In case Wilson's opponent had won the election, the plan was to appoint Charles Evans Hughes (Wilson's opponent) as US Secretary of State (second in line back then) and then Wilson and Marshall resigning. The modern equivalent would be for Mike Johnson (or whoever is speaker in 2028) to resign as Speaker of the House, the House electing Donald Trump as Speaker, and then Trump and Vance resigning. That's not going to happen.
Anti-roadblock #2: Repeal the 22nd Amendment.
If this gets done in time, easy-peasy; there's no longer a bar on becoming a third term President. This has come up before, almost every time the US has had a two term President since FDR. However, none of those repeal proposals had any legs.
Anti-roadblock #3: Repeal and replace the entire Constitution.
This, too, is a highly unlikely proposition. However, it has happened in other countries, so while highly unlikely, it is possible.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Possible improvement : Roadblock #4 is false. 3 USC 15 (d)(2)(B)(ii) specifically sets forth what possible grounds are valid in order to reject electoral votes, the qualification of the presidential candidates is not one of those grounds.

Possible improvement : Roadblock #5 while acceptable as a whole is in accurate in saying that the supreme court's "number one job is to ensure the Constitution is obeyed", as the supreme court allies all law and not only the constitution, and all courts apply the constitution. In fact, the roadblock is the courtS and the judiciary as a whole, not the supreme court.

Possible improvement : Anti-roadblock #1 is false. The positions set specified in the presidential order of succession (which are Speaker, president pro tem of the senate and secretaries) do not waive the presidential requirements of the constitution for the holders of these positions to be actual members of the line of succession. In fact, there are specific precedents of secretaries under Obama and Trump who, not being american-born, were fully valid secretaries of their various departments but not part of the line of succession. There is no reason for this not to apply to the Speaker.

@Governator Your edits were unacceptable. Please refrain from completely changing another person's answer. Write your own answer.

@DavidHammen I don't get it, you're knowingly keeping inaccuracies which are contradicted by written law ? What's the goal here ?

The corrected answer is here https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/89803/35459

@Gouvernathor It is your opinion that these are "inaccuracies contradicted by written law". David Hammen is entitled to hold a different opinion, even if you think it is foolish. Since this is his answer, you are not supposed to edit it in a way that changes his intent. (To clarify, it is a good thing to edit posts to correct inaccuracies, but if the OP reverts the edits, you just have to accept that.)

@EmilJeřábek For example, I did not object to Philipp's edit. Downvoting and voting to delete: that's fine. But as a general rule, do not ever edit an answer in a way that is very contrary to what the author of the answer wrote.

@DavidHammen You seem to be agreeing with me. Did you intend to direct the last comment to Gouvernathor?


The amendment seems to only bar election, rather than standing for election

Most election laws allow only candidates who are qualified to be elected and assume office.  If the constitution says that Alice can't be president, then most states' laws won't allow her to be on the primary ballot, much less the general election.  The secretaries of state (or election boards or whatever authority) of the several states would most likely reject any petition to put such a candidate on the ballot, with the details depending on the particulars of each state's election law.
That said, I looked for an example in New York law, and found that the matter is somewhat complicated by the electoral college.  I found a provision requiring candidates for "public office" to be eligible for the office, but also to be citizens of the State of New York, so this provision presumably doesn't apply to the presidency.  I found no similar provision for the presidency.  Perhaps the state is implicitly relying on the political parties not to nominate ineligible candidates, or perhaps I just didn't look hard enough.
This is basically what happened in Colorado for the 2024 election, only the Supreme Court ruled that a state government has insufficient authority to disqualify someone on 14th-amendment grounds in the absence of a federally imposed 14th-amendment disability.  That doesn't prevent a state from enforcing a federally imposed 14th-amendment disability nor indeed from enforcing other constitutional qualifications such as the 22nd amendment limitation.

if someone does attempt a third term and ends up being prevented, is there any punishment for attempting to break a constitutional term-limit?

Probably not, unless there was some sort of fraud or similar misdeed.  But that seems rather unlikely in this case.  It's not inconcevable that a state could enact a civil or criminal penalty for seeking an office for which one is unqualified, but there doesn't seem to be much benefit to it, at least not enough benefit to outweigh the costs: the possibility of abuse toward political enemies, for example.

"unless there was some sort of fraud or similar misdeed" - are you required to certify that you are eligible when standing for election in the US? If so, standing when you're not eligible (e.g. because of term limits) could be seen as electoral fraud - in the same way that there are stiff penalties for voting when ineligible (e.g. if I, as a non-US citizen, attempted to vote in a presidential election, I could face up to a year in prison).

@pwaring "are you required to certify that you are eligible when standing for election in the US?": For the presidency there are 51 jurisdictions for which that question must be considered separately.  But an accusation of fraud isn't particularly credible: the fact that the candidate had already been elected twice would be common knowledge.  For an untruthful statement to be fraud it has to mislead someone.

@phoog: Bizarrely, there does not appear to be any question on this form which would require candidates to certify eligibility at the FEC level. But there's probably other paperwork (e.g. for ballot access in DC, etc.), and I'm sure there's something on one of those forms.

@pwaring yes, you will need to for example show that you're a natural born citizen before you can assume the office of president. There was for example a lot of contention when Obama was installed when the legitimacy of the presented birth certificate was called in question (a question that was never properly resolved as far as I know, in the end the whole argument died a slow death and was forgotten).

@jwenting You are actually admitting to being a birther?  No, there was no non-racist reason to doubt it.

@phoog It might not be fraud, but it could still be perjury, no? I'm not sure about applications to appear on a ballot, but lots of forms that I've seen require attesting to some particular statement about eligibility to do what you're applying for under penalty of perjury. For example, a passport application requires declaring under penalty of perjury that you're a national of the United States and that your statements on the application or in support thereof are truthful.

@jwenting nobody has to show that they're a natural-born citizen of the US to become president.  If someone challenged the candidacy on those grounds in court, and if the challenge presented some credible evidence calling into question the candidate's citizenship of birth, then the candidate might need to prove it.  But that's never happened.  Obama's citizenship question certainly was resolved; if the Hawaii birth certificate had been fake then someone would have taken it to court and Obama would have been taken off the ballot.

@reirab yes, if there were a declaration subscribed under penalty of perjury along the lines of "to the best of my knowledge I am eligible" then a candidate filling after having reached the term limit could be at risk of prosecution.  But it is possible that no state has such a declaration, and anyway you have to know that you're lying to be guilty of perjury, and that is a fairly high bar for a prosecutor to clear.  The prosecutor has to show beyond a reasonable doubt that the candidate knew that the declaration of eligibility was false.

@phoog I mean, I would hope that most people who have served at least 1.5 terms as President of the United States would be aware of the 22nd Amendment and how many terms they've served. That seems like a pretty low bar. But, yes, you're right that there would have to be a declaration under penalty of perjury for that to be prosecutable. I'm not sure whether any states require such a declaration for ballot access.

It depends on the method they try to use.
A viable strategy would be:

while staying at least somewhat popular, or at least being portrayed as such by the media...
take strong personal control over the law enforcement hierarchy at both federal and many state level
do so in the election administration as well
defund, de-staff and demoralize the army
otherwise dismantle or disable the present checks and balances
diecredit the opposition to a great extent, e.g. by controlled media
grab more legislative power in the next legislative  election cycles
some other things (I am not expert at any rate)

... then they will be in a position to alter the legal framework or at least the status quo of the presidency as they see fit.
Pretty much a working recipe with a lot of success stories all over the world.

You can make army the vanguard of that change instead of defunding it.

Not responsive to the question, which explicitly says "I'm not asking how someone could get around the term-limit (there are plenty of questions discussing this), but what would happen in terms of process and punishment if they attempted to stand for election for a third time."

@alamar the police is the tool of choice these days and the army is somewhat out of fashion. After all, the police is pretty much used to acting against their fellow citizens. On the other hand, more or less adequate army is quite reluctant about the same. But I do not imply that the army is absolutely useless in this regard. I only say that the method is outdated and there is no recent examples.

@JohnBollinger If e.g. Obama brings the idea right now, he will be laughted at into coma at every step - friends and family, any size of any political party gathering, the primary elections, state and federal election offices, everywhere. The idea simply cannot be serious right now. On the other hand, 2 terms of gradual changes can get some different result.

If the candidate is one of 2 major parties (D/R), they both have this nifty thing called a Convention which chooses who the next nominee of their party is.
So, before the 3rd time candidate gets on federal ballots, they need to FIRST, manage to convince the voters at the Convention to vote for someone who is guaranteed to lose the party this election (as in, would be thrown off the ballot and cause the party to lose this cycle as a result).
DNC has superdelegates whose job it is to do just that. RNC doesn't have a formal mechanism, but they still have the votes.
Actually, even before Conventions, the 3rd party candidate needs to win Primaries/Caucuses. And the FIRST roadblock is there - the state party may not allow in-eligible candidate into their primary, in the first place. A Party is a private organization, governed only by its own internal rules, so they can pretty well do as they please and not admit the 3rd-time candidate at will. They may suffer political capital in doing so if the candidate is popular with the base... so this isn't a guarantee.

(This is a fixed version of another answer, with inaccuracies corrected. Fixes are sourced and in italics. For some reason fixing the original answer was not accepted.)
As far as I can tell, it is not a crime to run for any elected office in the US as an unqualified candidate. That said, there are a huge number of roadblocks that prevent unqualified candidates from being elected and then taking office.
Roadblock #1: Getting on the ballot.
It is up to election officials (typically headed by a state's Secretary of State) to keep unqualified candidates off the ballot. If a candidate is not qualified (and that includes running as a third term president), said candidate should not be appearing on the ballot. Some states even require potential write-in candidates to be qualified.
Roadblock #2: Ballot counters.
Assuming the election officials did their job, the official ballot counters don't need to worry about excluding votes for unqualified candidates. In states that don't certify who is/is not qualified to run for an office as a write-in candidate, they might have to toss write-in votes for, example, Mickey Mouse (a favorite write-in, where allowed).
Roadblock #3: The Electoral College.
The Electors swear an oath to the US Constitution, which includes the 22nd Amendment. In some states it has even been made a crime to be a Faithless Elector. That sets up a quandary if the winning candidate in some state passes the first two roadblocks but is indeed unqualified. Said electors are caught between a rock and a hard place. They might be violating state law by being faithless and voting against the elected unqualified candidate, but they might be violating state law by violating the US Constitution.
Non-roadblock: The US Congress.
The US Congress meets in a joint session on January 6 to certify the presidential election results. However, 3 USC 15 (d)(2)(B)(ii) clearly specifies what grounds are valid in order to reject electoral votes, and the qualification of a presidential candidate is not one of them.
Roadblock #4: The courts.
Suppose that somehow an unqualified presidential candidate did make it past all of the previously mentioned roadblocks and has been elected. Everyone who opposes this election will likely qualify as an aggrieved party in order to contest any of the "president"'s actions in court. In the US, all courts have the power and duty to apply the constitution.
Possible anti-roadblock: Side-skirt the 22nd Amendment.
This would try enacting Woodrow Wilson's bizarre scheme in 1916 should Wilson have not been elected to a second term. (He was narrowly reelected in the Electoral College so the scheme was never put into play.) The issue at hand back then was the very long lame duck session between the November election and the March 4 presidential transition. In case Wilson's opponent had won the election, the plan was to appoint Charles Evans Hughes (Wilson's opponent) as US Secretary of State (second in line back then) and then Wilson and Marshall resigning for Hughes to become acting president until becoming the actual president on March 4th. The modern equivalent would be for Mike Johnson (or whoever is speaker in 2028) to resign as Speaker of the House, the House electing Donald Trump as Speaker, and then Trump and Vance resigning.
The validity of such a scheme is not certain, because holding an office that is part of the presidential line of succession does not override the constitutional requirements for being president: age, US citizenship at birth, not having done more than 1 and a half terms already, and so on. In fact, during the Trump and Obama administrations, there have been several examples : for instance, Elaine Chao, Secretary of Transportations under Trump (also known for being Mitch McConnell's wife) was born in Taiwan and excluded from the line of succession during her tenure. In the scheme described above, if Trump as Speaker of the House does not qualify to be acting president, as specified in 3 USC 19 (b), that duty would fall upon the next person in line, presumably the president pro tempore of the Senate.
However, it is not clear whether having completed 2 terms (or one and one half...) constitutes a bar for being president or acting president, because the wording of the 22nd Amendment specifically bars someone from being "elected" president more than twice. As opposed to the other qualifications of ArtII.S1.C5.1 which mention "be eligible to the Office of President", and the wording of the 14th amendment which mentions "hold any office [] under the United States". Depending on the judge and the court, it may or may not hold.
Anti-roadblock #2: Repeal the 22nd Amendment.
If this gets done in time, easy-peasy; there's no longer a bar on becoming a third term President. This has come up before, almost every time the US has had a two term President since FDR. However, none of those repeal proposals had any legs.
Anti-roadblock #3: Repeal and replace the entire Constitution.
This, too, is a highly unlikely proposition. However, it has happened in other countries, so while highly unlikely, it is possible.

As a person succeeding to the presidency is not elected to the presidency, the 22nd Amendment does not apply as that amendment explictily states that a person shall not be elected to the presidency more than twice. In fact, the 22nd Amendment explicitly uses the word elected twice. Being elected to Speaker is not being elected to the presidency. The Supreme Court is Donald Trump's Supreme Court. Do you really think that they won't apply a very strict reading of the wording of the 22nd Amendment? All other restrictions (35 or older, US-born citizen, non-traitor) do apply.

@DavidHammen Ok, that makes sense. I'll incorporate that in the answer (eventually).

One other possible correction? I don't think it's 3 U.S.C § 19b that rules out a Speaker who isn't eligible for the office, but 3 U.S.C § 19e. At least, if "fails to qualify" includes constitutional eligibility requirements, then I'm not sure what the point of 19e is (and I think I'll actually ask about that on Law.SE).

@Idran 19b specifies how "that duty would fall upon the next person in line, presumably the president pro tem". But you are right that it's 19e that bounces back to the general constitutional requirements for the presidency.
